# Using function's optional argument's default value

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make a function use its optional parameter's value? For example, say I have,

```
public void myFunction(bool required, string optional = "This is optional") {...}
```

and I want to do something like this,

```
string possiblyNull = null; // the result of another function
myFunction(true, possiblyNull ?? possiblyNull : optional)
```

Comment: surround the call with an `if...else`

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can, however, use a classic `if (possiblyNull == null) myFunction(true); else myFunction(true, possiblyNull);`.

Comment: Sounds like bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# compiler embeds the parameter’s default value **whenever arguments are left out at the call site**. And in your case your want to call your method with that parameter. So, it is not possible, so you have to use that check either outside or inside of your method. If you really want to prevent using `if` clause while calling your mehtod, then you can change signature of your method so:

```
public void myFunction(bool required, string optional) 
{
    optional = optional ?? "This is optional";
    ...
}
```

And then call it so:

```
string possiblyNull = null; // the result of another function
myFunction(true, possiblyNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the default value at the call site. You'd need to have a check outside the method call.

```
string possiblyNull = null;
// ...
if (possiblyNull == null)
    myFunction(true);
else
    myFunction(true, possiblyNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are quite there but you only need to remove possiblyNull: while you passing the parameter to the method,
you can do like this...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string optional = "Test";
    string possiblyNull = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       // here you can check null 
        myFunction(true, possiblyNull ?? optional);
       // Or 
        myFunction(true);

    }

    public  void myFunction(bool required, string optional = "This is optional")
    {
       MessageBox.Show(optional);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that

- You don't want to just make `null` the default because that would mean the default wouldn't appear in Intellisense and the caller wouldn't see the default
- You could make some value the default and then check for `null`, and if it's null replace it with the default, but that would mean putting the default in two places

You could do this:

```
private const string OptionalValue = "This is optional!";
public void myFunction(bool required, string optional = OptionalValue)
{
    optional = optional ?? OptionalValue;
}
```

Now you get both. The default shows up in Intellisense and it's not repeated.

If it's just that you

- might need to pass a null value
- want to get the default value
- have to do so frequently enough that it's annoying
- can't modify the original method

you could create an extension for the class containing the method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    // I can't think of how this function name would not be awkward.
    public static void MyFunctionThatReplacesNullWithDefault(
        this ClassWithOptionalMethod target, bool required, string optional = null)
    {
        if(optional == null)
            target.myFunction(required);
        else
            target.myFunction(required, optional);
    }
}
```